# qt to c# what does : operator mean within struct

Tags: c#, c++, c, bit-fields

I have a block of code that i'm trying to covert from an old qt file into C# but i'm a little unclear what is going on in the struct within the union below.   I'm not sure what the ':' does... i'm guessing it sets the size but could not find any documentation on this.  Also since C# does not have unions what is the best practice for converting something like this.  Thank you

```
union uAWord
{
   uAWord()
     : m_AWord(0) {}

    struct sBcdAWord
    {
      quint32 m_O  :8;
      quint32 m_S  :2;
      quint32 m_D  :18;
      quint32 m_SS :3;
      quint32 m_P  :1;
    }
    sBcdAWord m_F;
    quint32 m_AWord;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is called BitFields. the portion sBcdWord is a 32 bit word, and each field is a portion of that word taking respectively 8,2,18,3,1 **BIT**:
So the word layout is as below:

- Bit0-Bit7 m_0
- Bit8-Bit9 m_S
- Bit10-Bit27 m_D
- Bit28-Bit30 m_ss
- Bit31 m_P

How to port this in C# depends if you are convettually porting the code, or if you need to PInvoke. In the case of PInvoke the best solution is probably to map sBcdAWord as an Unit32, and create some accessor strategy to mask on reading writing. If it is a code port, use separeted properties would be good unless there is  special needing in memory usage saving.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is used to declare bitfields. The number is the number of bits for that value. See for example http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03defbitf.htm

A good conversion to C# depends on the case I guess. As long as you are not too space-conscious, I'd just keep all needed values in parallel in a class.

Answer (score 0):

That initializes `m_aWord` to `0`.

Comment: Yes, it appears similar in nature to a chained constructor call in C#.

Comment: I suppose the trouble is about the ":" in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question, in C# you'd likely want a struct, and you'd need to use attributes to get union-like behavior out of it.

This particular example could be somewhat like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct uAWord {

    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    private uint theWord = 0;

    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public int m_P;
    [FieldOffset(1)] 
    public int m_S;
    [FieldOffset(3)] 
    public int m_SS;
    [FieldOffset(7)] 
    public int m_O;
    [FieldOffset(18)] 
    public int m_D;

    public uAWord(uint theWord){
        this.theWord = theWord;
    }
}
```

The `LayoutKind.Explicit` indicates you will tell it where in the memory to map each field and the `FieldOffset(int)` tells which bit to start each field on.  [See this for more details.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  You'd assign this struct by setting the `uint theWord` in the constructor, then each of the other properties would access a chunk starting at a different memory address.

Unfortunately, that actually isn't correct.  You'll need to use properties and do some bitmasking/shifting to get it right.  Like this:

```
struct uAWord {

    private uint theWord = 0;

    public int m_P {get {return (theWord & 0x01);}}
    public int m_S {get {return (theWord & 0x02) << 2;}}
    public int m_SS {get {return (theWord & 0x04) << 3;}}
    public int m_0 {get {return (theWord & 0x18) << 6;}}
}
```